# Правильно определить массив неизвестного размера

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Работаю с Google таблицей, в скрипте есть код, в котором идёт обработка нескольких массивов, заранее неизвестных размеров, и возникает проблема при создании нового массива и попытке присвоения значения элементам выдаёт такую ошибку

> TypeError: Невозможно задать для свойства "0.0" объекта undefined
>   значение "Вася"

Код такой:

```
var dat = '....' // строка разделённая запятыми
dat = dat.split(","); // преобразуем в массив
var dats = [[]]; // определяем злополучный искомый массив
                 // если задаю [[],[]] то ошибка пропадает,
                 // но я заранее создаю пустой элемент, 
                 // который может помешать в дальнейшем,
                 // если запись останется единственной.
var j,g = 0
  for (var i=0;i<dat.length;i++){ // делаем массив многомерным по 15 элементов
    j = Math.floor(i/15);
    g = i-Math.floor(i/15)*15;
    dats[j][g] = dat[i]; // ошибку выдаёт в этой строчке
    Logger.log("dats[j][g]")
  }
```

Подскажите как правильно определять массив, что бы в него можно было добавлять нужное количество элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего не существует элемнта `dats[j]`. Проверьте это

```
...
if(!Array.isArray(dats[j]))
  dats[j] = [];
dats[j][g] = dat[i];
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение, я сделал другое, но оно более сложное и корявое

Comment: Рад, что пригодилось. Обратите внимание, что, вероятно, вам придется искать максимально длинный массив в строке, чтобы потом все остальные строки привести к его размеру. Это надо для того, чтобы была возможность вернуть результат обратно в Таблицу через `setValues()`